# Trap on dbclick in GrapeJs editor

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

Is there an event or something else [GrapesJs](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs) to trap every dbclick on any components ?

Like component:selected or component:toggled.

Comment: you have to add more deatils .

Comment: I want to trap when a user do a double click on a component. when someone select a component, an event "component:selected" is fire but I don't find for double click.

Answer (score 0):

As long as i know, grapesjs don't have dblclick event registered, what we have is the component select here in the plugin grapesjs-preset-webpage.

https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-preset-webpage/blob/master/src/panels/index.js#L109

I'm using this code to do stuff at dblclick, maybe it can work to you:

```js
let canvasDoc = editor.Canvas.getDocument();
canvasDoc.addEventListener('dblclick', function (e) {
   //do stuff here
});
```

Comment: does it still work? The link is 404. And for gjs 0.27.1 I get 
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: Hi @addlistener these code is used by me nowadays, you should relly on your typescript error. Maybe your code didn't find the Canvas or event the editor itself.

Can you provide some code so i can help you?

Comment: Thank you!  I'm using the react version and the gist is  `<GjsEditor onEditor={editor => editor.Canvas.getDocument() } ... />`, where the document is undefined.  If it still works for you, it's already informative to me. Let me see if I can find sth myself first

Comment: I'm not using the react version, i'm using pure js version.